# :active state of button fades after clicking

Tags: html, css

I've a button that I'd like to be grey normally, and change colour and have a border when clicked, with that effect fading.

It's almost the reverse of this: 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPJVZB  but instead of the background colour and border fading in when you hold down left click, it is instant and then fades away

```
.btn{
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  background: grey;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.btn:active{
   background: green;
   color: white;
   outline: 1px solid white;
   outline-offset: -4px;
   transition: 0.5s;
 }
```

I can replicate the effect I want with the background, but the border never fades away. Can anyone help please?

** edit: I think I described this poorly (although the first two comments I think have answered my question - I think I have to animate the border color). I'm trying to get this effect to fade out with the border as well, a bit like this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BPJVZB

```
.btn{
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  background: grey;
  outline:none;
  border:none;
  transition: 0s .2s;
}

.btn:active{
   background: green;
   color: white;
   outline: 1px solid white;
   outline-offset: -4px;
   transition: 0s;
 }
```

Comment: I don't believe you can animate `outline` or `border` by setting it to `none` - you'd have to animate the *color*. A fade-out effect could be achieved using the `rgba` alpha channel:  `border-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);` to `border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0);` or something of that sort.

Comment: Indeed `none` is not a number value and so cannot be used in an animation/transition.

Comment: yeah, i think my problem is not being able to animate the border - although doesn't it kind of animate in? I've updated my question with a pen that shows what i'm trying to achieve more clearly, but what you've written sounds about right

Comment: @NickW I've also added an answer that I *think* accomplishes your goal, though if I'm misunderstanding, leave a comment on it and I'll see what I can do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is instant and then fades away

If I'm understanding correctly, you could make use of [CSS animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations). You define a start (green with white border, etc) and an end (initial state) to your animation, and then apply it to the button when it's `:active`.

```css
.btn {
  height: 4rem;
  width: 4rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: grey;
}

.btn:active {
  animation-name: btn-flash;
  animation-duration: 0.5s; /* Change to make slower/faster */
}

@keyframes btn-flash {
  from {
    color: white;
    outline: 1px solid white;
    background: green;
    outline-offset: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    color: black;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    background: grey;
    outline-offset: -4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">press</button>
```

Comment: I've added a new pen to try and make it a bit clearer, but something like that - although in your example the animation ends when the click ends. I'd like the background and the border to transition/fade. i think your edit has put me on the right track though, thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help. You could change `:active` to `:focus` but that would stop you from repeatedly clicking the button unless you were to first click outside of it to *lose* the focus state.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do this without javascript.

Try something along the lines of this (Using JQuery)

.your-element-to-color

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".your-element-to-color").click(function(){
        $(".your-element-to-color").css("background-color","#hexwhatever");
    });
});
```

You can make this background-color, border-color, any CSS value, as long as it is inside of this .css action.

Then, inside of css, add whatever transition you want for it.

```
.your-element-to-color{
    transition:background-color 0.2s; /* Or however much time */
}
```

You can do any CSS transition. font-size, border, border-color, border-radius, transform, background-size, almost anything.

The way that this works is it will pass a new css value of a color to the css file. JQuery if I remember does not support color changing with animation, however, it will support changing colors of CSS. Then, using a CSS3 transition, you can make it fade however fast or slow you want.

Read up a bit on the transitions and how they work. Good luck!